# how can i do scroll side to side to page between different Images

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

please i need to  scroll side to side to page between different Images  when user select the image it display and can change the image by scrolling like photo library in iPhone

the below my following code :

var Images:[String] = ["Febrewary.png","April.png","January.png","March.png","May.png"] // this is array of image how can i scroll between them?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    scrollView.delegate = self
    for i in 0..<colors.count
    {
        var frame = CGRect();
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i);
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true;

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: Images[i])

    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize =  CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(colors.count), self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
  }
```

Thanks Advance

Comment: You need to ask a specific question to get help. This question is too broad.

Comment: thanks friend i need to make scroll side to side to page between different Images

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Here are some ideas: 1) Inside your for-loop you're creating a `CGRect` and doing nothing with it, 2) You need a separate `UIImageView` per image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a UICollectionView rather than a UIScrollView for this.  If you set it to work horizontally it should do all the work for you.

Comment: thank you my friend i have collectionView which display all the photos which users save it and when he come to collectionView and select one image it display with full screen i need when user move finger to right or left the image is changed this is i mean

Comment: If you don't allow horizontal scrolling in you scroll view, you could use a gesture recognizer to detect the swipe motion and implement the image change in its action.  But if you allow scrolling in both axes, then there will be an ambiguity between scrolling the image and swiping to the next one.  Still you could use the gesture recognizer and change image when the scoll position is at its maximum on the swipe direction.

Comment: Thank you very much